# Jquery combining has() with is()

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am building a dropdown that needs jquery to change some classes for styling.
It works well this code that basically adds a class to an `li` that has a `ul` child

```
$('#nav ul li:has(ul)').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('dropdown')
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('dropdown')
    }
);
```

The issue I having is if someone clicks this link and doesn't move their cursor the `addClass` will not be triggered until the mouse leaves the element and `.hover`'s again.

You can see the issue here [click the Industry Sectors link and don't move the mouse](http://www.on-sitephysio.com.au/industry-sectors)

I have found `.is(":hover"`) but just can't work out how to get it working with the current `hover()`.
Can I keep them in the same function or is it not that simple?

Comment: The title doesn't convey at all the problem you are having though

Comment: This is a really strange way of approaching the problem. If you're just trying to display dropdown menus on mouseover, you can do it with CSS.

Comment: why are you reloading the page when the user is already at that page? and also the issue u mentioned does not appear for me in Chrome.

Comment: @redDevil you're right it is working in chrome, in firefox if the user clicks on industry sectors and leaves the mouse where it is, (which is a common occurrence) the .hover class isn't triggered until the mouse leaves the element and returns, i need to tell .hover it is already :hover'ed

Comment: @JezenThomas you need to look at the code a little closer, dropdowns are triggered via css, classes are added and removed with jquery because css couldn't style specific children > parents without jquery.

Comment: @Alexander feel free to tell me what title is more descriptive, I was wanting to know if I could combine a has() and is(), it may not be the best way.

Comment: Couldn't? Are you _sure_? It's trivial to achieve the same behaviour as the dropdown menu on the page you linked to, with only CSS.

Comment: as a workaround, you can check for a click on the list item and hide the dropdown once a click is registered.

Comment: @JezenThomas because the designer created a dropdown that had it's own hover style on the target I needed a way to target a li if it has ul children, I couldn't work out to do it with css.

Comment: @redDevil I will have a look at that, I am new to jquery so will see how to go about it, cheers.